# RISC-V: Handling multiple interrupts

Tags: riscv

Is it possible to give different priority for different interrupts in machine mode?  Unlike different mode interrupts, how does processor controls nested traps for same mode?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to give different priority for different interrupts in
>   machine mode?

As far as I understand, the different interrupts in machine mode have fixed priorities, from high to low: external, software, timer, synchronous traps, see 
[riscv-privileged-v1.10.pdf](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/blob/master/release/riscv-privileged-v1.10.pdf) end of section 3.1.14. Multiple external interrupts are prioritized by an interrupt controller such as PLIC described in chapter 7.

> Unlike different mode interrupts, how does processor controls nested
>   traps for same mode?

By stacking the global interrupt enable for the interrupted mode, and also the previous privilege mode, see section 3.1.7.

There are many subtleties to consider, but I hope the above broad answers leads in the right direction.